# Wrong button style when creating AlertDialog with androidx DialogFragment

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, androidx, material-components-android

Here is my root style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

And here is how I create dialog:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

        return AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity())
            .apply {

                setMessage(R.string.dialog_delete_service_message)
                setPositiveButton(
                    R.string.dialog_delete_service_positive_button
                ) { _, _ ->
                    listener?.onConfirmed()
                }
                setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_delete_service_negative_button, null)

            }.create()
    }
```

Fragment is subclass of `androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment`.

Here is how dialog is shown:

[image]

I want to show borderless buttons but dialog buttons are bordered. Is any style missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md)

```
new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
            .setTitle("xxxx")
            .setMessage("...")
            .setPositiveButton("..", null)
            .show();
```

and use this style in your app theme:

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    ...
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog</item>
 </style>
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way without using different class?