# Is there a way to change DatePickers button style?

Tags: android

Not just `DatePicker` and `TimePicker`, but a lot of dialogs I use from third party libraries look like this ever since I switched to `material design`:

[image]

Even when using android themes like HoloDark. I've tried changing buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle in the style and a few more related attributes, but none work. I assume the issue is they're using material buttons now which use different styling. But has anyone figured out a way to fix this? Thanks

EDIT: Just to clarify the issue is the button background being right next to eachother and not being transparent. Either adding a slight margin or making the buttons transparent will do for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrong button style when creating AlertDialog with androidx DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57654013/wrong-button-style-when-creating-alertdialog-with-androidx-dialogfragment)

Comment: @kAliert That might be using the alpha version of material themes since I don't have those attributes, but using         <item name="android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog</item>
 fixed it for me

Comment: Check also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57711522/2016562)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out adding

```
 <item name="android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog</item>
```

to my theme fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

you can use your customButton and applay custombutton style